Using Sidebar Button Jump in SwiftUI NavigationSplitView with NSHostingController on macOS
I get an unexpected Navigation sidebar jump when I try to use SwiftUI NavigationSplitView with NSHostingController.
The navigation sidebar button jumps when I press the navigation sidebar button on the window title bar.

Is there any way to have this sidebar not jump and be placed before the navigation title (i.e. "My Navigation Title") and still be using NSHostingController to host the SwiftUI View?

Thank you for your help and I have attached the relevant swift code below 


ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigation = NavigationChoice()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $navigation.selected) {
                NavigationLink(value: "View 1") {
                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            .frame(width: 10)
                        Text(verbatim: "View 1")
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(value: "View 2") {
                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                        Image(systemName: "doc.badge.arrow.up.fill")
                            .frame(width: 10)
                        Text(verbatim: "View 2")
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(value: "View 3") {
                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                        Image(systemName: "gear.circle.fill")
                            .frame(width: 10)
                        Text(verbatim: "View 3")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selection = navigation.selected {
                switch selection{
                case "View 2":
                    View2()
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("My Navigation Title")  //<---- this is my navigation title
        .frame(width:1000, height: 600)
        .fixedSize()
    }
}


final class NavigationChoice: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected: String? = "View 2"
}


WindowController.swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class WindowController {
    private var window: NSWindow?
    
    init() {
        showWindow()
    }
    
    func showWindow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = NSWindow(
                contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600),
                styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .resizable, .miniaturizable],
                backing: .buffered,
                defer: false
            )
            let myContentView = ContentView()
            
            let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: myContentView)
            guard let myWindow = self.window else { return }
            
            myWindow.contentViewController = hostingController
            myWindow.center()
            myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            myWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
            myWindow.display()
        }
    }
}


You can add .fullSizeContentView to your window's styleMask.
func showWindow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = NSWindow(
                contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600),
                styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .resizable, .miniaturizable, .fullSizeContentView],
                backing: .buffered,
                defer: false
            )
            let myContentView = ContentView()
            
            let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: myContentView)
            guard let myWindow = self.window else { return }
            
            myWindow.contentViewController = hostingController
            myWindow.center()
            myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            myWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
            myWindow.display()
        }
    }


Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10104/

how do I implement this with appkit?
